# External Mic not detected Macbookpro 11,1 CS4208

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, macbook-pro

My external combo jack mic always not detected, I used different headphones, And All working fine in OSX but not working when switching to Linux, I tried different distributions using the live boot,  and All the same issue, currently I am on Pop!_OS 21.04
Also Tried the latest version of Popos and the same issue.
[image]

pavucontrol

[image]

MY alsa info:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=1d06b188bb60fe99e9917dacac662d6af24ff4d7

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: Also note:  Ubuntu 21.04 is EOL thus all packages from Ubuntu should be treated as *insecure*. You can confirm with `ubuntu-security-status`. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/

Comment: Thanks you I will consider update